# Unable to deploy after being able to do do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am unable to deploy. When I attempt to I get an ExecJS::ProgramError: of some kind or another. It appears that I have something saved wrong possibly.

When I do mina deploy I get the following when it tries to precompile the assets:

```
I, [2015-09-10T20:56:37.873756 #5887]  INFO -- : Writing /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/public/assets/active_admin-60d95c165a548330a6b0a5146f774b1d.js
   rake aborted!
   ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: punc ()) (line: 42497, col: 2, pos: 1368711)

   Error
   at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:10623)
   at js_error (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:10842)
   at croak (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:19086)
   at token_error (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:19223)
   at unexpected (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:19311)
   at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:27292)
   at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:30019)
   at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:30777)
   at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:30869)
   at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:31312)
   at expression (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:31625)
   at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:27102)
   at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:30019)
   at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:30777)
   at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:30869)
   at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:31312)
   at expression (/tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:31625)
   at /tmp/execjs20150910-5887-3tjxs5js:2359:21477
   (in /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2359:10623)
   js_error ((execjs):2359:10842)
   croak ((execjs):2359:19086)
   token_error ((execjs):2359:19223)
   unexpected ((execjs):2359:19311)
   expr_atom ((execjs):2359:27292)
   maybe_unary ((execjs):2359:30019)
   expr_ops ((execjs):2359:30777)
   maybe_conditional ((execjs):2359:30869)
   maybe_assign ((execjs):2359:31312)
   expression ((execjs):2359:31625)
   expr_atom ((execjs):2359:27102)
   maybe_unary ((execjs):2359:30019)
   expr_ops ((execjs):2359:30777)
   maybe_conditional ((execjs):2359:30869)
   maybe_assign ((execjs):2359:31312)
   expression ((execjs):2359:31625)
   (execjs):2359:21477
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in `evaluate'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.4/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /home/deployer/sband/tmp/build-14419077823206/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !     ERROR: Deploy failed.
```

help with problem

Answer (score 0):

Looking like problem with your js file , first try to precompile your code by this `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace`and see you got same error or not. if yes then resolve the js error.

Comment: the problem is not gone

Comment: @user3555986 when you have run  above command what error you got?

Comment: `... 
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/home/deployer/sband/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:183
Tasks: TOP => environment`

Comment: @user3555986 your are using bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace not rake assets:precompile --trace right?

Comment: `(See full trace by running task with --trace)`